# Constant HTTP request timeouts for C# Selenium tests running on TFS server

Tags: c#, http, selenium, tfs, timeout

Update 2014-10-23: tl;dr: turn on interactive mode / interactive logon.

Longer version: We found a workaround. Enabling interactive mode (basically an open RDP session) is allowing the tests to be executed. Previously people had to do this to get Selenium/etc. to run. In Visual Studio 2010 it was fixed. But something seems to have regressed. Our setup is a Windows VM with the build controller component of TFS installed on it. Our theory is that something in preventing the build controller from interacting with the desktop, OR there are different networking or security settings which are preventing interaction with the webdriver. We're going to open a ticket with Microsoft to see if they can fix this regression.

---

I know about the issue of intermittently getting these kinds of timeouts. This is not that issue. I'm getting the timeouts 100% of the time, for ALL Selenium operations (click, find element, etc.).

My tests were running perfectly for several days in a row, and then *something* changed on the server. My WebDriver hasn't changed. Still using the same ChromeDriver.exe as before. My code hasn't changed. To my knowledge the build definition hasn't changed.

Things we have tried:

- Turn off the firewall that might have been interfering
- Reboot the server
- Turn off parallel test runs
- Rolled back recent Windows updates

I don't know what else to try at this point. Ideas?

We're running the .NET bindings at version level 2.40. (I know there's a 2.43.1 update out there, but I doubt it would help). ChromeDriver.exe should be the latest stable version; I checked it recently.

Error Message:

> Test method Company.BlackBoxTests.WebUI.Portal.Tests.LocationsShould.AddPlan threw exception:
>      OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL `http://localhost:40901/session/37a7c64c5ef189acf896ff9d3af34e67/execute` timed out after 60 seconds    . ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Error Stack Trace:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
Company.BlackBoxTests.WebUI.Portal.PageObjects.BasePage.WaitForAjax(IWebDriver driver, String action, Boolean longWait)
```

Comment: Did the network guys "fix" something?

Comment: What version of ChromeDriver + Chrome? (The two go hand in hand).

Comment: ChromeDriver is v2.9.248315. So it looks like I'm two versions behind. Chrome version I'm not sure yet. Will update this comment when I hear from the admin.

Comment: Chrome version is 38.0.2125.104 m

Comment: I am currently trying to update to ChromeDriver 2.11 and the 2.43.1 .NET Selenium bindings to see if it'll make any difference.

Comment: No luck. Same error with the updated ChromeDriver and updated .NET bindings.

Answer (score 1):

As you said: Enabling interactive mode (basically an open RDP session) is allowing the tests to be executed.

Another solution: If you run the TFS agent as a Service, then be sure to check "Allow service to interact with Desktop"

[image]

This might not work if your application cannot be run as the Local System Account. In that case you must not run the Agent as a service; You can only run it in Interactive Mode. So far I have had good results with the service this way, though.

Note, I had to do this, too:  add the "no-sandbox" flag when starting up the ChromeDriver